# check-config errors on Linux 3.19.0 kernel, configured under Ubuntu 15.04 x86-64

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, x86

I'm new to configuring Linux kernels, and am receiving the following errors when running config-check:

```
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != m): CONFIG_NVRAM                                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'powerpc-powerpc-e500mc': 'y', 'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<boot essential on powerpc LP:942193>
check-config: FAIL (n != y): CONFIG_VFAT_FS                                     
y mark<ENFORCED> note<needed on arm to ensure we can write the kernel when replacing>
check-config: 41/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 42/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 42/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: 42/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 38/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic-lpae: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 38/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/arm64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 38/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/ppc64el-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR           
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 35/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/powerpc-config.flavour.powerpc-e500mc: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR           
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 35/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/powerpc-config.flavour.powerpc-smp: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR           
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 36/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/powerpc-config.flavour.powerpc64-emb: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_NVRAM                                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'powerpc-powerpc-e500mc': 'y', 'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<boot essential on powerpc LP:942193>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR           
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 34/43 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.tnqExc0fHn/CONFIGS/powerpc-config.flavour.powerpc64-smp: loading config
check-config: /home/aaron/linux-3.19.0/debian.master/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_NVRAM                                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'm', 'armhf': 'm', 'i386': 'm', 'powerpc-powerpc-e500mc': 'y', 'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<boot essential on powerpc LP:942193>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_THERM_ADT746X                               
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc-powerpc-smp': 'y'}> note<LP:#923094>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_XEN_ACPI_PROCESSOR                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'i386': 'y', 'amd64': 'y'}> <boot essential on XEN host>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_EFI_VARS                                    
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'i386': 'y'}> note<EFI boot requirement (d-i) LP:#837332>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR           
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA                                
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'armhf': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (y != -): CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX                       
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'powerpc': '-', 'ppc64el': '-', '*': 'y'}>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_METHOD                  
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}> note<SECURITY: allows arbitrary execution>
check-config: FAIL (n != -): CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO                              
p mark<ENFORCED> policy<{'amd64': 'n', 'i386': 'n'}>
check-config: 34/43 checks passed -- exit 1

*** ERROR: 12 config-check failures detected
```

I've not done this before, but I'm guessing that when I configured the kernel, I had some options that didn't gel together. How do I read these logs in order to go back and change my configuration so that it can be compiled successfully for x86-64? Do I have to satisfy config checks for other platforms as well, or is that not something I'm understanding correctly/need to worry about?

Comment: I have the same problem, actually.

Answer (score 2):

from the page:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
it said :
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs # you need to go through each (Y, Exit, Y, Exit..) or get a complaint about config later

So, I tried do it one by one followed it's question form several architecture even I just want to build amd64. And it works without error from check-config.

Comment: it works (mac host, ubuntu 16.04 guest on virtualbox)!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guide 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

While 
`apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`
facilitates you get the same version as your current linux kernel in your ubuntu, configuring it is a tedious task.
when you use 
`fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs`
you are loaded with myriad of options. Once you start compiling with

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

you might face errors as you posted above.  You can then

1. Compare the one with your own version of config under

   /boot/config-3.xx.-generic
   or something similar to that.
   Once you figure out the difference try setting the same through `menuconfig` or through `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` to make sure the configs are almost same(you can ignore some minor settings in between) and then start building the kernel  (can guarantee success of build if done correctly)
2. (remember its not recommended, but you can give it a try) copy the items from the `/boot/config-3.xx.-generic`  to the build location `kernel_src/debian/build/build-generic/.config`  (this is generated once the build starts and fails).  compare the diffs(barring the minor ones) and modify the configs accordingly, and then start build. (cant guarantee success of build)

I have done it for Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox. (cross check with the linux version of the one you want to build and the installed kernel, it shouldnt differ by more than few digits in its 4th number (corrections, patches,security fixes) ex. 3.19.0-25 vs 3.19.0-39) http://www.linfo.org/kernel_version_numbering.html

if it complains on ncurses use,

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```